# Angular 7: Use external script in component

Tags: angular, typescript, twitch

I'm trying to use the Twitch API to embed a channel in my web app.

The instructions are as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>

    <!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a Twitch.Embed object that will render within the "twitch-embed" root element. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        channel: "monstercat"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've included the `https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js` file in my `assets` folder and angular.json.

```
    "scripts": [
      "src/assets/twitch/twitch-embed-v1.js"
    ]
```

My component files looks like this:

```
import Twitch from '../../../../../assets/twitch/twitch-embed-v1';

export class TwitchPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    const options = {
      width: 854,
      height: 480,
      channel: '424976424',
    };
    const player = new Twitch.Embed('twitch-embed', options);
    player.setVolume(0.5);
  }

}
```

The script appears in my sources panel in Chrome devtools, but the following error is produced:

`Embed is not a constructor`

What is the barrier to using the script properly?

Comment: Please check this:

https://therichpost.com/how-to-include-custom-js-file-to-all-components-in-angular-7

Answer (score 0):

The v1 of twitch doesn't have TypeScript typings yet, this will come in v2. You should not add the scripts to your assets folder. What if there is an update from twitch? You will have to update your assets folder manually.

Anyways, I think, to use the twitch SDK you can do the following:

```
npm install twitch-js@next
```

And in your TS:

```
import * as Twitch from 'twitch-js';

new Twitch.Embed({...});
```

Comment: Do you have a working stackblitz or code? This was my original approach but leads to the same error. I figured bringing the script internally would eliminate variables, not to keep it that way in the long-term.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve encountered the same problem and that’s why I decided to implement a Typescript wrapper for the Twitch interactive embed player. This is 100% compatible with Angular so if you still need a way to achieve this please check this repository out. Hope it helps ^^

https://github.com/frozencure/twitch-player